# How to clear the stage selection area on Crayon Physics Deluxe?

Tags: crayon-physics-deluxe

I bought this game from Humble Bundle and I let my eight years old niece to play it for a while. However, she drew a lot of ugly-looking stuff on the stage selection area (inside the first island).

I tried to clear it with the right mouse button, but it deleted the drawing that came with the game too :-( I also tried to start a new game, but that area remained painted with my niece's drawings.

How can I clear the stage selection area while restoring the original paintings that were there when I first installed the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I found another folder used by the game and deleted it, that cleared the stage selection area. The folder I had to delete is (I'm using Windows 7 64 bits):

`C:\Users\<<My Username>>\AppData\Roaming\Crayon Physics Deluxe`

Now I have a clear stage selection area again!

Answer (score 2):

You can press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to bring up the menu and click "Clear Map" in it.

Answer (score 0):

Nah you're screwed. You need to uninstall the game and every folders from it and re-install. I know it's a pain .... it happened to me :S

Comment: I installed it via Steam, and I tried reinstall it and delete the folder inside My Documents but it did not work :-(

Comment: @Weslei you should check if Steam uses cloud storage as well

Comment: @Weslei You can uninstall through Steam as well. Right-click the game in your library and choose "Delete local content...". Once that's done, download the game again to reinstall.

Comment: @Anna I did that and it did not reset the drawings.